# How to convert MGRS to decimal degrees

Tags: ios, coordinates, coordinate-systems

I am making an iPhone application. I want my app to Convert MGRS co-ordinates to Decimal Degrees.

How to do this Programatically ?

Comment: Have a look at [earth point](http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx).. if u want it calculate it runtime.. then i will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched and founded : [Determine the grid coordinates of a point on a military map](http://www.armystudyguide.com/content/Prep_For_Basic_Training/Prep_for_basic_land_navigation/determine-the-grid-coordi.shtml) . Here, they have given the manual process of how to determine the six-digit grid coordinates for the point on the map with a 100meter tolerance. You can go through that process and can create your Objective-C code for that.

Take a look at this C++ Class : [GeoCoords.cpp](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/1.30/GeoCoords_8cpp_source.html) .

Another thing I founded is :  [GDGeoCocoa](https://github.com/gdey/GDGeoCocoa#what-is-mgrs) . It is the Collection of Classes to convert co-ordinates. You can check it if you can found something useful for you.

Using the above links and Apple Documentation for [Converting Between Coordinate Systems](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/MapKit/MapKit.html) , I think you can achieve what you want.

GoodLuck !!!