# Does ios7 location services provide MGRS coordinates

Tags: ios7, coordinates, core-location, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to find out if ios7 location services provides MGRS (Military Grid Reference System). I can't find any reference to MGRS on Apple's developer site.

I did run across this post on here

[How to convert MGRS to decimal degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16998404/how-to-convert-mgrs-to-decimal-degrees)

That makes me think someone did. Also there are apps in the app store that provide other location in other grid coordinate systems. I am just wondering if they are offloading those conversions to some external service or how they are going about that. I will admit I haven't tried to code anything. I've been working out a design for what I want to do on paper and am at this point just researching.

If anyone can give me a definitive answer or point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `CLLocationManagerDelegate` gives you `CLLocation` objects that contain `CLLocationCoordinate2D` structs.  That contains latitude and longitude in decimal degrees in the WGS-84 reference frame.   See: [Core Location Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) documentation.

If you want another coordinate system you can do the conversion on your device, no need for an external service.  One way to convert between coordinate systems is to use the [AGSGeometryEngine](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_geometry_engine.html) class to convert geometries (point, lines, polygons) between different coordinate systems.